# Can't see the crop button. So, can't crop the image when using the library to crop images

Tags: android, kotlin

The toolbar for accepting, canceling, or rotating the image does not
appear. I use the Android-Image-Cropper library, https://github.gitop.top/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper. I'm still a
beginner and so far I don't understand why I can't do it.

---

```
private val cropImage = registerForActivityResult(CropImageContract()) { result ->
    if (result.isSuccessful) {
        // use the returned uri
        val uriContent = result.uriContent
        val path = REF_STORAGE_ROOT.child(FOLDER_PROFILE_IMAGE)
            .child(CURRENT_UID)
        uriContent?.let { path.putFile(it).addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                showToast(getString(R.string.toast_data_update))
            }
} }



private fun startCrop() {
    cropImage.launch(
        options() {
            setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            setAspectRatio(1, 1)
            setRequestedSize(600, 600)
            setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
        }
    )
}
```

[What I have now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NHbc.png)

[As I would like it to be:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVX3e.png)

Comment: You can use some other library if this library doesn't provide enough features.

Comment: @Karan Mehta, this library should do it, but something went wrong with me

Comment: Then please check documentation of that library

Answer (score 4):

Does your app theme has no action bar? If yes, you should add this to your manifest. I added this and it helped me

```
<activity android:name="com.canhub.cropper.CropImageActivity"
 android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
```